# Android AsyncHttpClient call wait for finishing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, http

in my Android application I've to make sometimes synchronous HTTP calls. As this is not possible from the main UI thread I'm trying to circumvent the problem with the usage of the `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient` and a handler. In my code I try to wait for the call the finished:

```
public class someclass {
...
//asynchronous HTTP handler for Android
private static AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(); 
...
public void somemethod() {
...
httpClient.get(request, handler);
    ...
    //waiting for call to be finished
    do {
        Thread.sleep(100); //for testing only
        log.info("sleeping...");
    } while (!handler.isFinished());


    response = handler.getBody();
    log.info("Async resp = " + response);
 ...
```

I wrote my own handler class:

```
    public class MyAsyncHTTPResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {



    private String header = null;
    private String body = null;
    private int status = 0;
    boolean finish = false;

    public MyAsyncHTTPResponseHandler() {
        super();
        log.info("init Http handler ");
        finish = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
        log.info("starting Async Get");
        finish = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {


        body = new String(responseBody);
        status = statusCode;
        finish = true;

        log.info("Async Get worked fine " + responseBody);
    }



    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, java.lang.Throwable error) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        log.info("Error in executing URL get " + statusCode + " " + responseBody);
        finish = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return status;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finish;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this is not working. The `onStart()` method will be executed but the loop is running forever. The `onSuccess()` method will not be called.

If I comment out the loop the body response will be empty. As I can see in the log in this case the `onSuccess()` method will be called but after my log statement in `somemethod()`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add `volatile` keyword to the variable `finish`.
Or use synchronization:

```
public synchronized void setFinish()
   {
       finish = True;
   }

   public synchronized boolean isFinished()
   {
       return finish;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me (neither volatile nor synchronized). The init method will be called but not the success method...